# Trading Chosen-Ciphertext-Protection for Double encryption

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, multiple-encryption

Straight to the point: I'm trying to implement double encryption using two cipher suites. One (#1) of them is a stream cipher without any checksum/authentication guarantee, the other (#2) is an AEAD algorithm (AES-OCB).

On [blog.cryptographyengineering.com](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/02/02/multiple-encryption/), it says:

> ### The ugly [of multiple encryption]
>
> ...
>
> 3) Plaintext distribution issues. Maurer showed [one more interesting result](ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/crypto/publications/MauMas93a.pdf), which is that in a cascade of ciphers, the entire construction is guaranteed to be as secure as the first cipher, but not necessarily any stronger. This is because the first cipher may introduce certain patterns into its output that can assist the attacker in breaking the second layer of encipherment. Maurer even provides a (very contrived) counterexample in which this happens.

First, my code encrypted using #2 first, then #1, so that the whole ciphertext had a checksum. Then I noticed how bad my idea was: The attacker would just have to crack #2, then the rest is easy.

Are there any disadvantages of encrypting with #1 and then #2?

<sub>#1 and #2 don't use the same password, I've omitted KDFs for simplicity.</sub>

Comment: AES-OCB by itself should be fine and there should really be no need for double-encryption. As such it is (probably?) advisable to use the cited result and encryption first with #2 and then with #1. Even though a point can be made that if you do #1 and then #2 you will also authenticate the keystream of the stream cipher which _could_ be helpful.